# Wrap PHP code in its own span or echo it differently on mobile

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a bit of code added to my `header.php` to show a custom WooCommerce cart which includes the number of items as well as the total cost. I want to style the cart slightly differently on mobile devices so that the word "item/items" does not display.

This is the code I have added:

```php
<a class="cart-customlocation" 
   href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?> " 
   title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
   <?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
</a>
```

I thought perhaps wrapping the word items into its own span might work, but for the life of me I have not been able to, or alternatively, if there is a way to on mobile echo only the number and not the word, that would be welcomed too.

I hope someone can help with how to wrap the items in a span, I have spent many hours trying different ways and I am not having much luck.

Comment: I’m guessing `_n( '%d <span>item</span>', '%d <span>items</span>', …` would probably be enough here already to achieve this …

Comment: I would suggest going the route of adding a span (with css media defines) instead of simply omitting the word(s) on mobile. The point of making a reactive website, is that changes in ANY browser's width, will self-adjust the page without requiring device detection or reloading the page.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I tried this and gave the spans a class. I then used `display: none;` to test it and what I saw was the "items" word disappear momentarily and then re-appear once the page fully loaded, any idea?

Comment: Try and inspect the element using your browser dev tools, and check what styles are getting applied. Maybe this gets overwritten by a rule with higher specificity from a stylesheet that loads after the one you tried to apply this from. Also possible perhaps, that the content itself got switched out via JavaScript, because it tries to automatically update this in the background.

Comment: @CBroe perfect, thank you. I had an AJAX bit of code to update the cart totals that was overriding it. Thank you for your help.